# how to prove this inequlity $\ln(\frac{p}{q}) \le \frac{p-q}{\sqrt{pq}} (0 < q \le p)$ by means of integral inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

I can solve it by introducing a function, but I need to prove it by applying integral inequalities such as the holder inequality or the schwarz inequality.

Comment: Would you count $f(x)\le g(x) \Rightarrow \int_a^b f(x)dx\le \int_a^b g(x)dx$ as an integral inequality?

Comment: No, not these basis ones, more like the Holder inequality

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\ln\frac{p}{q}\leq \frac{p-q}{\sqrt{pq}}$ for $0<q\leq p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122041/prove-ln-fracpq-leq-fracp-q-sqrtpq-for-0q-leq-p) – CS solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/122061.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can recognize this is the equivalent to prove
$$
f(x) = \ln(x)\le \sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = g(x) \quad \text{when} x \ge 1
$$

Easy to see $f(1) = g(1)= 0$

We also have
$$
g'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}^3} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}^3}\right) \ge \sqrt{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}^3}} = \frac{1}{x} = f'(x)
$$

Thus $f(x)\le g(x)$ when $x \ge 1$ as a result of integral inequalities.

Comment: For your sign is wrong comment, note it's $\ln p/q$ not $\ln q/p$. Also numerator is $p-q$, not $q-p$.

Comment: oh, you are right. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Also, you can rework the inequality to be $t\le \sinh t$ which is the obvous inequality $1\le \cosh t$ integrated.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I am looking forward to an answer using Holder inequality or Minkowski inequality or Schwarz inequality, for I can prove it in the way you do.